# Array sort leaves one element in the wrong position

Tags: java, sorting

I am trying to sort an array in ascending order and I came across a problem. The code sorts the array but it takes the last number and places it in the first position of the array. So for example when ordering 2,3,4,1 the output is 4, 1, 2, 3.  How do I take the number 4 and move it behind the number 3?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] numbers = {2, 3, 1, 4};
        int holder = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
            for(int j = 1; j < numbers.length; j++){
                if(numbers[i] < numbers[j]){
                    holder = numbers[i];
                    numbers[i] = numbers[j];
                    numbers[j] = holder;
                }
            }
        }

        // prints array
        for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
            System.out.println(numbers[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
4
1
2
3
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two major problems.

One is that you're swapping some elements twice. You want to always make sure that `i` is less than `j` so that `numbers[i]` is to the left of `numbers[j]`. The way your loops work, in later iterations `j` starts out lower than `i`. For instance, when `i` is 2 the inner loops starts with `j` at 1. To fix this you can always start `j` at 1 place higher than `i`:

```
for(int j = i + 1; j < numbers.length; j++) {
```

If you fix that you'll notice the second problem: the array is sorted in reverse! That's because the `<` comparison is backwards. You want to swap items when the left one is *larger* than the right one, not when it's smaller. If it's smaller they're already in the correct order.

```
if(numbers[i] > numbers[j])
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks as though one possible, inefficient solution would be to change:

```
for (int j = 1; j < numbers.length; j++) {
```

To the following:

```
for (int j = 0; j < numbers.length; j++) {
```

This inadvertently double-swaps every value in the array, but works!

Comment: That actually solved my problem. Mind explaining what I did wrong?

Comment: It's a poor fix. It leaves the incorrect `<` comparison in place, and instead it works around it by swapping every element pair twice! Two wrongs happen to make a right here, but they don't make a good answer.

Comment: @user10526837 The other answers explain it well enough. Keep in mind that your sorting method is `O(n^2)` and that better ones exist; I thought this solution was pretty interesting, so I posted it. However, this isn't something I'd use in production if I were you!

Answer (score 2):

You must modify a bit at the loop.

```
for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length-1; i++){  //modify at this line
    for(int j = i+1; j < numbers.length; j++){  //also modify at this line
        if(numbers[i] > numbers[j]){  //modify to get ascending oder
              holder = numbers[i];
              numbers[i] = numbers[j];
              numbers[j] = holder;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have marked them. This is InsertionSort algorithm. First, it detect the leastest number and move to position 0, then detect the leastest number among remaining number and move to position 1, then detect leastest number among remaining number and move to position 2, and so on,..

Comment: It's still a bubble sort.